# My Webpack Encore loads only file name, not file contents?

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I have something like this in JS file:

```
const icon = require('path-to.svg').default;
div.innerHTML = icon;
```

When I build my assets using default Webpack 5.6.0 with rule `test: /\.(svg)$/, loader: 'raw-loader'` the result is awesome:

`<div><svg>...</svg></div>`

But when I use Symfony Webpack Encore (latest) with (and without too) rule, the result is:

`<div>path-to.svg</div>`

Only file name! Not file contents!

Why? How can I get the same result with Webpack Encore as with normal Webpack?

Answer (score 0):

Just add raw-loader by yarn\npm and prepend it to required path:

```
const icon = require('!raw-loader!path-to.svg').default;
```